# Javascript function using given argument & object sent from Geolocation

Tags: javascript, json, geolocation

I'm trying to make a function that takes in a users location and then loops through a JSON file of station locations to determine which is the closest station. The issue I am having is with how to include both the location object and the JSON file as arguments in the function.

I am getting the location by using:

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(findNearestStation);
    } else {
        return "James Street";
    }
}
```

I then want to use the function findNearestStation to take in a JSON as an argument and use the location passed by getLocation to find the nearest station. Something like this:

```
function findNearestStation(position, json) {
    var UserLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var UserLong = position.coords.longitude;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.stations.length; i++) {
        compare and find the min distance...
    }
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an anonymous function:

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            findNearestStation(pos, json);
        });
    } else {
        return "James Street";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Reggie Mind upvoting and accepting my answer then?

Comment: I've upvoted but apparently "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded but not visibly displayed". Thanks again.